# how can I obfuscate the code with ionicframework?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic5

I have an ionic 5 app with Cordova and I need to obfuscate the code for both Android and iOS.  Can someone guide me on how to do it, Any plugin?  I tried the cordova-plugin-crypto-file plugin but it doesn't work for IOS.  Thank you!!

Comment: Googling "how to obfuscate ionic code" yielded a top result of https://mevasanth.medium.com/ionic-how-to-obfuscate-your-code-37194ffca3f8